# How can I add to add alert function to this code

Tags: pine-script

Please I need help on how to add alert function to this code or how I can rewrite the code so it will support my condition I don’t know if I’m making sense at all I’m new to pine-script

```
    study(title="MACD",     shorttitle="MACD")

    // Getting inputs
    fast_length =      input(title="Fast Length",        type=integer, defval=12)
    slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", type=integer, defval=26)
    src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
    signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 15)
    sma_source = input(title="Simple MA(Oscillator)", type=bool, defval=false)
     sma_signal = input(title="Simple MA(Signal Line)", type=bool, defval=false)

    // Calculating
    fast_ma = sma_source ?   sma(src, fast_length) : ema(src, fast_length)
    slow_ma = sma_source ? sma(src, slow_length) : ema(src, slow_length)
     macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
    signal = sma_signal ?    sma(macd, signal_length) :    ema(macd,        signal_length)
    hist = macd - signal


    /////////
    h = input(8.,'Bandwidth')
   src = input(close,'Source')
    //----
    n = bar_index
    var ln = array.new_line(0) 
    if barstate.isfirst
     for i = 0 to 499
    array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))
    //----
   float y2 = na
   float y1 = na
   float y1_d = na
    //----
    line l = na
   label lb = na

   if barstate.islast

    for i = 0 to min(499,n-1)
    sum = 0.
    sumw = 0.
    for j = 0 to min(499,n-1)
        w = exp(-(pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))

        sum += src[j]*w
        sumw += w
    y2 := sum/sumw
    d = y2 - y1
    l := array.get(ln,i)
    line.set_xy1(l,n-i+1,y1)
    line.set_xy2(l,n-i,y2)
    line.set_color(l,y2 > y1 ? #ff1100 : #39ff14)
    line.set_width(l,2)  
    if d > 0 and y1_d < 0
        label.new(n-i+1,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=#39ff14,textalign=text.align_center) 
    if d < 0 and y1_d > 0
        label.new(n-i+1,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=#ff1100,textalign=text.align_center) 
    y1 := y2
    y1_d := d
```

I tried adding this conditions but still not working

```
    Bullmode = d > 0 and y1_d < 0
    Bearmode = d < 0 and y1_d > 0

    Long  = crossover (macd, signal) and Bullmode
    Short = crossunder (macd, signal), and Bearmode

   alertcondition(Long, title = "BUY", message = "Long signal was generated on {{ticker}} at {{timenow}}")

   alertcondition(Short, title = "SELL", message = "Short signal was generated on {{ticker}} at {{timenow}}")
```

I would really love to get this solved thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set up your alerts? It is not enough to have it in code you have to manually set them. https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000595315-how-to-set-up-alerts/

Comment: I still get error while trying to save and apply the code

Comment: What's the error? Can you just share the code that produces the error?

Comment: Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Script could not be translated from: |B|var ln = array.new_line(0)